# Does htpasswd authentication prevent Google from crawling my site?

Tags: web-crawlers, authentication, googlebot

I have a site that I want to continue testing before I make public, so I don't want Google to start crawling the site as there will be a large amount of garbage content during testing.

I currently have authentication set up using htpasswd, will this prevent site crawlers or robots from crawling my site?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, if the site requires authentication then robots will not be able to crawl it.

You can also specify a robots.txt file so that the entire site is disallowed